How do I write page code without repetition? - nuxt 3
Now if I had a page /product :
<script setup lang="ts">
definePageMeta({
  pageTransition : {
    name : "anime",
    mode : "out-in",
    onEnter() {
      console.log("enter");
    }
  }
});

</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <NuxtLink to="/order">order</NuxtLink>
  </div>
</template>

I had, for example:
/prefs
/order
/user
/about
I do not want to repeat this code on each page. Is there a way to write it in one place?
I tried making composables but it didn't work.
I mean, how do I write definePageMeta in one place for more than one page...
Knowing that I know about the nuxt.config.ts method, I can add pageTransition, but hooks such as onEnter did not work for me
global pageTransition hooks not working - Nuxt 3

Not sure if you follow my question but I've also updated it.

To avoid repetition, you have a lot of ways, you could:

use reusable functions
use abstractions to wrap your stuff
dynamic pages
use CSS selectors on top of Nuxt layouts

Being DRY is something that a lot of people aim for no particular reason and it can actually lead to premature optimizations. Some repetitions are not always bad.

More detail:

if you need to write something into 5 pages, just write it as usual with nothing fancy
if prefs, order, user, and about could be a dynamic page like category, then you could have only 1 single .vue page
if you have >100 .vue pages with nothing in common, then use a composable, or wrap it into the same layout and apply CSS to it


How do I share the code above with more than one page?

@none you have page1, page2 etc, maybe a dynamicPage with an id so that we don't need to have 15 duplicated pages.

No, they are not dynamic pages, but just as an example...I have more than one page

I mean, how do I write definePageMeta in one place for more than one page,...

I modified the question...reload page
